# JWT flow in launcher-csharp demo

Tags: docusignapi

I'm playing now with launcher-csharp demo from DocuSign GitHub. It works fine with Authorization code grant flow. But when I try to run JWT flow, an exception is thrown in this call:

```
        public void UpdateUserFromJWT()
        {
            this._authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:ClientId"],
                this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:ImpersonatedUserId"],
                this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:AuthServer"],
                DSHelper.ReadFileContent(DSHelper.PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:PrivateKeyFile"])),
                1);
```

Exception says that server returned an **"consent_required"** error.
This error description in "How to get an access token with JWT Grant" documentation section says that it means that user did not give his consent, which is not my case, or something is wrong with URI configuration. I carefully checked DocuSignJWT section in appsettings.Development.json.

- **"ClientId"** is copied from "Integration Key" field in settings for this application. It is the same as used for Authorization code grant flow.
- **"ImpersonatedUserId"** is copied from "User ID" field. The same value is in the "API Username" field in the user edit form. The same value was returned in the user "sub" field when running in Authorization code grant flow.
- **"AuthServer"**: "account-d.docusign.com".
- **"PrivateKeyFile"** is file name there private key for this application is stored as is, with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----".

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide consent for JWT first.

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code
&scope=signature%20impersonation
&client_id=your integration key
&redirect_uri=your **encoded** callback url from the ikey settings
```

for example "https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9090%2Fds%2Fcallback".

Comment: I was sure that this step is included in this client method. If not - it should be included in the demo or at least mentioned as prerequisite step to run the demo. I'll try this approach.

Comment: Tank you, it works. After passing such URI to my browser and giving a consent the demo works with JWT flow. Still it is strange that all this not implemented in demo and not mentioner in the demo readme.